# data not saved successfully using database in android

Tags: php, android

Hi In My application I have some number of student names and roll no and clicking save button data not inserted into database and using toast message it's showing only single name and roll no nothing showing and data not inserted.

**Attend.class**

```
public class Attend extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView studentName;
    EditText Firstname,stRoll;
    CheckBox present;
    String[] class_name, section_name;
    String[] words;
    String name;
    String roll;
    Button save;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

         save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save); 
         Firstname  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentname );
         Firstname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         stRoll = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rollnumber ); 
         stRoll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //save.setText("Record Saved Sucessfully");
                name = Firstname.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(name);
                roll = stRoll.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(roll);
                Toast.makeText(
                        Attend.this,
                        "Result : " + "\nStudentName : " +name
                        + "\nRollno : " + roll,

                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("save","");
                System.out.println(data);
            }


        });

        String class_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("class_id");
        String section_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_id");
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Result : " + "\nclassName : " + class_id + "\nSectionName : "
                        + section_id,

                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final String queryString = "class_id=" + class_id + "&section_id="
                + section_id;
        /*String result = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("getStudent",
                queryString);*/

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("getStudent",queryString);
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();

    }
    public ArrayList<StudentDetails> parseJSON1(String result1) {
        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result1);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                StudentDetails user = new StudentDetails();

                user.setStudentname(json_data.getString("student_nme"));
                user.setRollno(json_data.getString("roll_no"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }

    public ArrayList<StudentDetails> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                StudentDetails user = new StudentDetails();
                // user.setId(json_data.getInt("class_name"));
                // user.setClass_id(json_data.getInt("section_name"));
                // user.setSection_id(json_data.getInt("section_id"));
                user.setStudentname(json_data.getString("first_name"));
                user.setRollno(json_data.getString("roll_no"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }

    void addHeader() {

        tr = new TableRow(this);

        studentName = new TextView(this);


        studentName.setText("StudentName");

        studentName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        studentName.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        studentName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(studentName, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);

        TextView RollNo = new TextView(this);
        RollNo.setText("RollNo");
        RollNo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        RollNo.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        RollNo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(RollNo, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);
        TextView Present = new TextView(this);
        Present.setText("Present");
        Present.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Present.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Present.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(Present, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);

        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<StudentDetails> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            StudentDetails p = (StudentDetails) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            Firstname = new EditText(this);
            Firstname.setText(p.getStudentname());
            Firstname.setId(p.getId());
            Firstname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Firstname.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);

            Ll.addView(Firstname, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            EditText stRoll= new EditText(this);
            stRoll.setText(p.getRollno());
            stRoll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            stRoll.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(stRoll, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);
            CheckBox present = new CheckBox(this);

            present.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            present.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(present, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

**save.php**

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
    mysql_select_db("login");
    $name = $_POST['name'];
$roll = $_POST['roll'];
    $q=mysql_query("insert into save (student_name,roll_no) values('$name','$roll')");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            $json_output[]=$row;

    print(json_encode($json_output));

    mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: have you tested it?
trying to make a post to the webpage with postman (a extension to chrome)

Comment: yes but showing undefined json json_output in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_connect\save.php on line 13
null

Comment: Try echo mysql_error();
To get the error message :)

Comment: it's giving same message

Comment: you haven't defined $json_output start by doing this before your while loop = $json_output = array();

Comment: can you please edit my code because I am not getting any error

Comment: See my answer :), i have posted the whole code there

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having is because there is no array to put the data in ($json_output)

if you define $json_output there should be no problem

**save.php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("login");
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : $_GET['name'];
$roll = !empty($_POST['roll']) ? $_POST['roll'] : $_GET['roll'];
$query = "insert into save (student_name,roll_no) values('$name','$roll')";
$json_output = array();
if (!mysql_query($query )) {
  $json_output[] = mysql_errno() . ": ".mysql_error();
}else{
  $json_output[] = true;
}

print(json_encode($json_output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_connect\save.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: roll in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_connect\save.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_connect\save.php on line 9
[]

Comment: if you get those errors, then your post isn't right :), since the error means you dont put it as POST to the server (properly get) 

I have made changes to my answer to fix some other things

Comment: I know, i changed that for making it more clear what happened :)

Comment: can you please tell me where i did mistake

Comment: Nothing showing clicking save button by using toast message I am printing studentname and roll no.studentname showing only one value and rollno nothing showing and data not inserted into database

Comment: Lets make a change :),
i have changed so it doesn't care about get or post

Comment: Hi In My java file if I debugging it's showing roll variable as empty